# Riemann problem for general Scalar Conservation Law

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

The Riemann problem for Burgers' equation $u_t +(f(u))_x = 0$, where $f(u)=\frac{1}{2}u^2$, has a shock solution:
$$
u(x,t) = 
\left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
&u_L &&\text{if}\quad x<st \\
&u_R &&\text{if}\quad x>st \, .
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
with Rankine-Hugoniot jump condition for $u_L > u_R$
$$s = \frac{f (u_R) − f (u_L)}{u_R - u_L} $$

My question is that does this solution satisfy Riemann problem for any general Scalar Conservation Law $u_t +(f(u))_x = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does, since it is obviously a solution on either side of the shock and satisfies the Rankine-Hugoniot condition. The nonlinearity $f$ only affects the shock. Of course this is not the case for non-piecewise constant solutions.